# Selenium c# random click to the ClassName

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to do random clicks to the ClassName in Selenium c#.
This is my code, please, help to understand what is wrong here. It doesn't work.

```cs
List<IWebElement> elements = new List<IWebElement>(_driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("mvp-vid-box-wrap mvp-vid-marg")));
Random random = new Random();
int num = random.Next(0, elements.Count);
elements[num].Click();
Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: `elements` and `class_elements` are not the same thing...

Comment: @Jonathan, yes it's my mistake.thanks

Comment: @Jonathan I have changed it, but again didn't work

Comment: When you print elements.Count, what value do you get?

Answer (score 0):

```
 //I did this in main so I needed to create a new object to call my driver
 Program p = new Program();

 p.driver.Url = "https://www.javatpoint.com/selenium-webdriver-locating-strategies-by-class-name";

 //IWebElement list = p.driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ddsmoothmenu"));

 //Here I use XPath instead of class to better retrieve the contents of the list im accessing
 List<IWebElement> elements = new List<IWebElement>(p.driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@class='ddsmoothmenu']/ul/li/a")));

 Random random = new Random();
 int num = random.Next(0, elements.Count);
 elements[num].Click();

 //Writes the amount of elements in your element list to the console.
 Console.WriteLine("There are " + elements.Count +" elements in this list");
```

I ended up having to use XPath for this to work before I did the element list only had one object in it so there was ever only one item the program was actually adding to the list. After using XPath it was populated by 20.

Side note, there is an issue starting at index 14 and beyond for me where the item in the index is "Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable". So you may want to make sure that not only is your XPath correct but that all the actual information it grabs is useable.